# Construct a chain of logical connectives

Tags: logic

I came across the following question and am having quite a bit of trouble with it.

below is my question:

p ↔ q is logically equivalent to (p ∨ q) → (p ∧ q)

Comment: It helps to remember that $a\implies b$ is equivalent to $\neg a \vee b$.

Comment: like this -(p ∨ q) ∨ (p ∧ q)

Comment: actually i stuck here, not idea coutinue

Comment: @JMoravitz Better would be to remember the continuity properties of $\to$, namely $(P\lor Q\to R)\equiv(P\to R)\land(Q\to R)$ and $(P\to Q\land R)\equiv(P\to Q)\land(P\to R)$. These are constructively valid and quickly reduce this problem to four cases, two of which are trivial, and the remainder are exactly the definition of $\leftrightarrow$. This also shows that this whole equivalence is constructively valid which wouldn't be obvious if we used material implication and which is nice to know even for non-constructivists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write both propositions in conjunctive normal form.  The first one is:
\begin{equation}
p \iff q \\
(p \implies q) \wedge (q \implies p) \\ 
(\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee p) 
\end{equation}
The second one is:
\begin{equation}
(p \vee q) \implies (p \wedge q) \\ 
\neg (p \vee q) \vee (p \wedge q) \\ 
(\neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee (p \wedge q) \\ 
(\neg p \vee p) \wedge (\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee p) \wedge (\neg q \vee q) \\ 
1 \wedge (\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee p) \wedge 1 \\ 
(\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee p)
\end{equation}
So they are equivalent.